# Sort results by price only for a single page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby I am required to sort the products on a minified version of PLP in descending order.
How do I go about doing this?Currently I am using CategoryPageController and manually sorting searchPageData.getResults() list using Java.Is this the correct approach?If no,what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

When you make the search, you can actually provide the sort criteria on the PageableData object you send to the search facade.

```
final PageableData pageableData = new PageableData();
pageableData.setSort("price-desc"); // Or your solr price sorting code
solrProductSearchFacade.categorySearch(categoryCode, searchState, pageableData)
```

This way you will get the data sorted directly and not using cpu time (response time respectively) to sort it in the controller. If you don't have solr sort configured you see how it is done here. [Hybris Wiki](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/b2531b4fc4744f42a50d2bae2ec76c12.html)

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your comment.Actually I was making my own URL here,like q=:fq:color:red,I was passing the parameters to my method which accepts all the parameters which a method of CategoryPageController accepts.I tried passing sort=price but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try with "price-desc" ?

Comment: ,you are saying for passing sort=price-desc right in the URL,while framing it?Do I have to configure price as a sort field in solr.impex for it?